# How to render ValidationError in Django Template?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, validationerror

I am new in Django, and I ask community help.

Now I I'm working on user registration and I want to do password validation: if passwords are not repeated, a message appears below the bottom field. As far as I understand, `{{ form.errors }}` must be used to render the error text specified in `ValidationError` , but when this error occurs, its text is not displayed on the page.
Please tell me how to solve this problem. Perhaps I did not quite understand how Django forms work.
I tried the solutions suggested in other answers, but unfortunately nothing worked so far.
Thank you.

**`forms.py:`**

```
from .models import CustomUser

class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                            label="Адрес электронной почты",
                            widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                        'placeholder':'email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='Пароль',
                            widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                            'placeholder':'password'})                                                            )
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label='Пароль(повторно)',
                            widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                            'placeholder':'confirm password'}))


    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise ValidationError({'confirm_password': 'пароли не совпадают'})


  class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email", "password", "confirm_password")
```

**`views.py:`**

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('pages:index')

    form = RegisterUserForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="users/sign_up.html", context={'form': form})
```

template:

```
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'users/css/style.css' %}">
<head>

<div class="text-center log-in-bg rounded">
    <img class="mb-4" src="{% static "users/images/logo_sign_in.png" %}" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-dark">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</h1>
    <form method="post" class="form-signin">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.email.label_tag }}
        {{ form.email }}
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.confirm_password }}
        {{ form.errors }}

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-sign-in btn-block">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help. I hope my question is not too primitive - I'm just at the beginning of learning Django, I may not know some things =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in view. This is corrected view:

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('pages:index')
    else:        
        form = RegisterUserForm()
    return render(request, template_name="users/sign_up.html", context={'form': form})
```

I was making new request to form. And context with mistakes was cleaned.
`else` using helped me to save this context. By other side SamSparx answer helped to understand me, how to use add_error.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1)

Generally speaking, validation errors in clean() appear in

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

...because they are not linked to a particular field. In this case, it involves two fields. If you include the above in your template, and modify your error message to...

```
raise ValidationError('пароли не совпадают')
```

...then the error should show on your page.

Option 2)

Looking closer, I see  you have tried to add it an an error message for the confirm_password field. While that's not the default, if you want to handle it that way you can remove the current `raise ValidationError` lines and use the following in your clean method to assign the error to a particular field.

```
self.add_error('confirm_password', 'пароли не совпадают')
```

Comment: I tryed 1 option. I changed my form:
I changed ValidationError, like you recommend, and add to template '''{{ form.non_field_errors }}'''
Unfortunately error is not displayed